# ASP.NET and FedEx integration

Tags: asp.net, fedex

i am doing FedEx integration with asp.net project. The web service works correct but, I have some doubts about the API code

Anyone know what is the use of `RateRequestTypes` object in FedEx API? Can you please tell what is the purpose of the following lines in the code

```
request.RequestedShipment.RateRequestTypes = new RateRequestType[2];
request.RequestedShipment.RateRequestTypes[0] = RateRequestType.ACCOUNT;
request.RequestedShipment.RateRequestTypes[1] = RateRequestType.LIST;
```

Comment: Have you thought about talking to FedEx?

Comment: no, because it is very basic level question.

Answer (score 3):

The RateRequestType is if you have an Account with Fedex you will get Account based rates, otherwise List base rates which are more expensive.  Most people when developing an api for fed ex use account based rates.

Answer (score 1):

> RateRequestTypes object in FedEx API?

Simple answer, no.  You need to look at the documentation FedEx (should've) provided you.

If the problem is elsewhere, such as not understanding the messages being passed to and from, then take a look at [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/).  I find this is worth its weight in gold when debugging web services.